# Converting number in sentences to word in python

Tags: python, numbers

I am having a text where i have some number in the sentence , i only want to convert the number to word format. How can i solve this . I have written a code for that but that does not work as i am passing text to 'function' instead of number. how do i do that

I have tried the following code.

```
import num2words


def convert_num_to_words(utterance):
      utterance = num2words(utterance)
      return utterance

transcript = "If you can call the merchant and cancelled the transaction and confirm from them that they will not take the payment the funds will automatically be credited back into your account after 24 hours as it will expire on 11/04 Gemma"

print(convert_num_to_words("transcript"))
```

Expected result is

"If you can call the merchant and cancelled the transaction and confirm from them that they will not take the payment the funds will automatically be credited back into your account after twenty four hours as it will expire on 11/04 Gemma"

i.e. number 24 in text should be converted to word (Twenty four)

Comment: What does this actually print?

Comment: it prints nothing just balnk

Comment: You must define what is a number that you want to translate into a word. Spaces around digits are Ok, and / is not, but what about punctuations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do it to every word of the string, and only if it is numeric, and also remove the quotes beside `transcript`, also do `num2words.num2words(...)` not just  `num2words(...)`:

```
import num2words

def convert_num_to_words(utterance):
      utterance = ' '.join([num2words.num2words(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in utterance.split()])
      return utterance

transcript = "If you can call the merchant and cancelled the transaction and confirm from them that they will not take the payment the funds will automatically be credited back into your account after 24 hours as it will expire on 11/04 Gemma"

print(convert_num_to_words(transcript))
```